# z3c.form reference widget - able to re-order and pick both AT and Dexterity content in Plone

Tags: plone

Is there a reference widget for Plone 4.1+ which would be able to pick and reorder both Archetypes and Dexterity content.

Namely this widget would be used to define dropdown menu order and items for a folder (pick and reoder items inside folder)

Comment: Looks like I asked almost the same question over a year ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290243/z3c-form-reference-widget-able-to-re-order-and-pick-both-at-and-dexterity-cont - List widget with custom vocabulary it shall be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

https://github.com/miohtama/webcouturier.dropdownmenu/blob/master/src/webcouturier/dropdownmenu/menusettings.py